# implementing bst in racket

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement a bst(binary search tree) in racket. The bst is a recursive list 
(list x leftChild rightChild) where leftChild and rightChild are lists themselves
I wrote the following code

```
(define (insert bst x)(
     (cond 
       [(null? bst) (append bst (list x '() '()))]
       [(<= x (car bst)) (insert (cadr bst) x)]
       [else (insert (caddr bst) x)]  
     )))
```

when I write

```
(insert (insert null 8) 9)
```

it gives an error: **function call: expected a function after the open parenthesis, but received (list 8 empty empty)**
Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Did you define `list` to be something that's not a function earlier in the file? Also, you have an extra pair of parentheses around the `cond`. In general, it's hard to give you feedback if you don't post enough context to reproduce your issue (e.g., what language setting are you using?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error reported happens because there's an erroneous pair of `()` surrounding the `cond` expression, that makes Scheme try to execute a procedure when there's none. But there are several logic problems beyond that, you're not actually *building* a list when an element is inserted, and there's a case missing - what happens if the element already exists in the tree?. This should work:

```
(define (insert bst x)
  (cond 
    [(null? bst)
     (list x '() '())] ; this is the correct way to handle the base case
    [(= x (car bst))   ; this case was missing
     bst]              ; simply leave the tree as it is
    [(< x (car bst))   ; if this happens, recursively build a list
     (list (car bst) (insert (cadr bst) x) (caddr bst))] 
    [else              ; if this happens, recursively build a list
     (list (car bst) (cadr bst) (insert (caddr bst) x))]))
```

This is how you'd use the procedure:

```
(insert (insert (insert (insert null
                                10)
                        5)
                16)
        13)

=> '(10 (5 () ()) (16 (13 () ()) ()))
```

Comment: oh i get it!! i am relatively new to racket so thnx fr your help

Comment: btw is there any differnece b/w (list 1 2 3 (list 1 2 3)) and '(1 2 3 '(1 2 3))

Comment: @ishan3243 nope, they're the same thing

Comment: the first one outputs (list 1 2 3 (list 1 2 3)) but the second one outputs (list 1 2 3 (list 'quote (list 1 2 3)))

Comment: @ishan3243 sorry, my mistake. They would be the same only if you remove the inner quote (it's unnecessary), otherwise they're different